# Initiate jQuery UI Tabs with no tabs active and all panels hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) in a project. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to have all the panels hidden when the document loads, until a tab is clicked. By default jQuery UI starts with an activated tab and the corresponding panel visible. I know you can specify which tab to have active initially, but I'd like to have **no** tabs active and no panels displayed at the start.

My code is pretty straightforward:

```
<div id="tabs">

     <ul>
          <li><a href="#faq1">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#faq2">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#faq3">Link 3</a></li>
     </ul>

     <div class="faq-panel" id="faq1">
          <!-- content -->
     </div>

     <div class="faq-panel" id="faq2">
          <!-- content -->
     </div>

     <div class="faq-panel" id="faq3">
          <!-- content -->
     </div>

</div>
```

And the jQuery is standard:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

So everything is working as it should right now, I just want to make this one tweak. I've searched and searched but I haven't seen any documentation on this. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the API doc, it looks like if you set active to false and collapsible to true, your desired behavior is possible - http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Matt suggests in the comments, it is:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({collapsible: true, active: false });
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/z66fX/)

Comment: This used to work but as of 1.10 active:false makes the first tab active.

Comment: @TomKincaid My jsFiddle linked above uses 1.10 and it works fine.

Comment: I used this for jQuery Mobile by adding data-collapsible="true" data-active="false" to the tabs widget. Also works great, thanks.